# FactoryGirl string together has_many relationships (i.e. User -> Blog -> Post )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Let's say I have three models: User, Blog, and Post.  My user model will have:

```
User Model
  has_one :blog
  has_many :posts through: :blog


Blog Model
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts

Post 
  belongs_to :blog
```

When I do a factory, I can do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title "something"
    content "long text"
    blog 
  end
end
```

Which creates a post belonging to a blog.  What I don't see is what I should put in :post so that FactoryGirl creates the user, then creates a blog belonging to that user, and then creates a post belonging to that blog/user.  I didn't really see anything in FactoryGirl's documentation to address this.

Answer (score 1):

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :post do
    title "something"
    content "long text"
    blog 
  end

  factory :blog do
    user
    # blog attributes
  end

  factory :user do
    # user attributes
  end
end
```

Then

```
@post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
@blog = @post.blog
@user = @post.blog.user
```